# How to do Page Navigation without memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I have a WPF application with a frame.
`<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Height="200"/>`
When I use the Navigate() method to navigate to a new page the old one seems to stay in memory.
When I use the Navigate() method multiple times the process eats up more and more memory.

I tried to call the Garbage Collection manually which didn't work.
Setting the page to KeepAlive="False" also didn't seem to help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are implementing the Dispose method correctly?  Is everything that can be disposed, being disposed?  Also, how are you determining that ' old one seems to stay in memory'?

Comment: You must never force garbage collection if you care about performance. KeepAlive is false by default. Please run a memory profiler to ensure that you really have created a memory leak. The profiler will also show you the piece of code that is causing this leak. If you can still not solve your problem, you must post a minimal viable example that reproduces the issue so that we can review it. Make sure that your pages unsubscribe from any events and free/dispose all allocated resources before unloading. You can handle the Unloaded event for this purpose.

Comment: Just having an increasing memory usage do not in itself indicate a memory leak. Use a memory profiler.